# How to access RoomDatabase from local fie path in android?

Tags: android, android-room

am new to room database i am having one doubt i have downloaded the room database from google drive and stored it in local file manager from that path how can i manage room database i have searched a lot but none of it helped me so please someone tell me how to do this now let me post what i have tried so far:

```
Room.databaseBuilder(context, RoomDB.class, "storage/emulated/0/mm/mm.db") .allowMainThreadQueries().build();
```

i have give file path to builder method but everytime while inserting am getting new value can someone help me ! Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

In order to do this, you must first copy your database file to `data/data/YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME/databases/`, before running any queries.

Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9109438/how-to-use-an-existing-database-with-an-android-application) and [this](https://github.com/humazed/RoomAsset/blob/master/room-asset/src/main/java/com/huma/room_for_asset/RoomAsset.kt) for more informations and working examples.